# how to terminate chrome (that started with "--user-data-dir="profilename"" argument) in vbscript

Tags: typeconverter

this snippet code is working in powershell but i dont know the code for vbscript

```
  $scriptName = "myprofile"
    $profileArgs = "--flag-switches-begin --user-data-dir=..\profiles\{0} --no-default-browser-check --allow-outdated-plugins --disable-logging --disable-breakpad --flag-switches-end" -f $scriptName
    $filterString = "Name='chrome.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%{0}%'" -f $scriptName # $profileArgs would be better, but for some reason gives an error
    (Get-WmiObject win32_process -filter $filterString).Terminate()
```

Comment: You might get better results if you ask for help solving a specific problem, rather than requesting that your project be done for you. For example, asking how to terminate a process in VbScript would be (in my opinion) a better question.

Comment: Set sh = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Comment: sh.run "powershell.exe -noexit (Get-WmiObject win32_process -filter (""Name='chrome.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%{0}%'"" -f ""master1"")).Terminate()"

Comment: The above code gives me an error

Comment: Name=chrome.exe : The term 'Name=chrome.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:39 + (Get-WmiObject win32_process -filter (Name='chrome.exe' AND CommandLi ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Name=chrome.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException